# Let each user update their own profile, add skills on their dashboard

Tags: php, dashboard

Am looking for help in creating an environment where the user is able to update their profile by uploading their image and add their skills. I have already set up the user sign up form where each user sees the same page after logged in. These pages appear to all users which are access controlled pages( visible only when logged in). Everything is done using PHP.

As soon as the user logs in it shows - Logged in as "User" so that the user sees that they are logged in. I have created some similar access controlled pages.

I want each user to be able to update their own profiles with a simple profile pic and their skills like `html`, `writing`, `web coding`, etc. How to make it happen for each registered user?

I will be adding lot of users for this site who will be able to manage their own dashboard.

The best example site would be oDesk or elance where the user is able to update their skills, and which can be viewed by the Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for Comment I am successful in sorting out the prob of user recognition for the few pages that I have set up for the users once logged in.**

You are definitely going to need a database to hold information for each of your users. Start looking into MySQL server and once you have one setup, follow some tutorials for [php mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) and [php form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). The below is extremely rough but it should give you an idea of how to attack your problem. **Good Luck!**

**index.html**

```
<form action="addSkills.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="skill"/>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**addSkills.php**

```
$skill = $_POST['skill'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user (skill) VALUES('$skill') WHERE userId = $_COOKIE['userId']")
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

This is a huge undertaking, you should try separating this into tasks and try working on each task at a time. One place to start would be able to navigate from page a to page b and still being recognized as logged in, once you do that look into forms and submitting forms.

Comment: I am successful in sorting out the prob of user recognition for the few pages that I have set up for the users once logged in.

Comment: @Codeobsession I updated my answer with a little bit of more information, the answer is extremely rough but I feel like that should give you an idea on how to start...

Comment: Thank you for this code. It is useful to have an idea. I will check with it and be back.

Answer (score 1):

I know where you are coming from in starting out simple to do this in PHP, but to make the best use of your time I would recommend to use a framework such as Joomla. Joomla is written in PHP and you might even be able to find extensions for Joomla many which are free, so you might not even have to write any code yourself or very little. What I do is with Joomla is use it as a framework, look for extensions and then look to write my own when needed.

joomla.org

Comment: Thanks but I can't start over again from the beginning again. My site is already working and the pages are in html and php extensions right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You need some way of identifying the user who's submitting the form on that page (since they're "logged in" you should already have that available as a `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` variable.

Then you just take that information and insert or update their profile in your database.